# How to make my Visual Studio code look like the one shown in babel JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, babeljs

I downloaded babel JavaScript by Michael McDermott from this link: [Babel JavaScript](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel)

And I would like to know how to make my font look the way it looks on the example, especially the more pronounced curly braces. Any Ideas?

Comment: Please add code for whatever you tried yet

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title with a question mark since you are asking a question. I also masked the link with a user friendly text to make it more readable. I added more tags so that your questions reaches to more users. And lastly I have corrected some grammatical mistakes. Good luck!

Comment: It says in the description: `My favorite is Theme - Oceanic Next (shown in the screenshot below)`. [Get that theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=naumovs.theme-oceanicnext).

Comment: To change the syntax highlighting settings just go to "Tools" > "Options" > "Environment" > "Fonts and Colors" > "Text Editor".  Some documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/index?search=syntax+color